# How to use functions?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, function, methods

I define a function in a separate .m file and then when I want to use it (in other implementation files), I just don't know what to import, to actually see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a header that declares the function and import that. So if you have the following file:

#### MyFavoriteTransformer.m

```
NSString *MyFavoriteTransformer() {
    return @"Hot Rod"; // Come on -- he's awesome!!!!
}
```

You'll want to have a corresponding file like this:

#### MyFavoriteTransformer.h

```
NSString *MyFavoriteTransformer();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you already have a matching `.h` file for your `.m` file, you just need to add `#import "MyUtilityClass.h"` to the header file of whatever other class you want to use your class from.